# Error in running my server using nodeJs express

Tags: node.js, express

While running my server using nodeJs express, I go below error:

```
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option server.js:16:9
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option server.js:16:9
C:\openshift\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:291
    throw new Error(msg);
          ^
Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at C:\openshift\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:291:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Router.route (C:\openshift\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:287:13)
    at Router.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\openshift\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:318:16)
    at Function.app.(anonymous function) (C:\openshift\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:412:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\openshift\nodejs\server.js:31:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
PS C:\openshift\nodejs>
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to pass to the `#get` method is out of scope and therefore is `undefined` hence the `[object Undefined]`.

Post your code and it'll be easier to help you out.